# Can't create project in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I am trying to create a project in the Google Cloud Console but I can't associate it to a an organization:

[image]

The list of organizations is empty. How can I create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a error with Google Cloud Console:
https://status.cloud.google.com/
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/developers-console/19001