# Unable to create a new project on google developer console

Tags: youtube-api, google-developers-console

I want to get access to the youtube API but am unable to create a new project on the google developer console. It asked me to select a parent or organization folder (I did not need to do this before) but failed to let me create one or edit/delete any current ones.

Any help is appreciated!

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fowx.png)

Comment: I'm getting this too and I was in the MIDDLE of a "project" that has now disappeared. I think Google is experiencing an outage of some kind right now. So glad I'm not going crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a service outage according to this similar question: [Can't create project in Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106863/cant-create-project-in-google-cloud/55107273#55107273)