# Cannot create project in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I saw a similar question in
[Can't create project in Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106863/cant-create-project-in-google-cloud)
which posted in months ago, 
is this problem still not fixed?

[Empty location listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjYyi.jpg)

Update:

---

Error message on `gcloud projects create`:

```
$ gcloud projects create ione20190911 ERROR: 
(gcloud.projects.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Google Cloud Platform service
has been disabled. Please contact your administrator to restore service. 
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure violations: 
- description: Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled. 
Please contact your administrator to restore service. 
type: SERVICE
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Error printed? Context of creation (personal or company subscription)? Number of existing project?

Comment: I have the same problem when I tried to select the Location when creating a new project, the location list is empty, the new project cannot be created. This is a company account and I have 1 existing project. I attached a image in my post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue that you are referencing in your question was fixed on 2019-03-11. I tried to reproduce your issue and everything works for me. It may be transient issue or your specific configuration. Please provide more detail for the context of creation of the project, your location, network, some firewalls, proxies? Dan you see any errors in the browser console? Please update the question.

You can also try to create new account just to check if the issue is tied to your specific configuration.

As a workaround try using Cloud Shell [gcloud command to create project](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/create):

```
gcloud projects create [PROJECT_ID]
```

Update:

---

Seeing your error message I can assume that your G-Suite account has disabled access to the Google Developers Console service.

Check in your [G-Suite Admin console](https://admin.google.com/) Apps -> Additional Google services if Google Developers Console is enabled. [For more information check this questions responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603145/unable-to-create-project-in-google-cloud-cloud-service-disabled-by-admin-plea).

Comment: I tried using the cloud shell and encounter error below

jpek@cloudshell:~ (pekjoosiong)$ gcloud projects create ione20190911
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled. Please contact your administrator to restore service.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - description: Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled. Please contact your
      administrator to restore service.
    type: SERVICE

Comment: Hi @PJS did it work for you? If it was the case, please accept my answer, for better visibility for another users.

Comment: I am still waiting for our google admin to grant me right to access Google Developers console server, will update this thread once I verify it. Thanks